# Cannot place text inside file using linux

Tags: linux, file, input, putty

I have installed moodle in AWS EC2 instance. But **config.php** file is missing. And I created a file using **

> touch config.php

** command. But I couldnt place my content inside that file.

My content is

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG); global $CFG; $CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mariadb'; $CFG->dblibrary = 'native'; $CFG->dbhost 
= 'localhost'; $CFG->dbname    = 'moodledb'; $CFG->dbuser    = 'root'; $CFG->dbpass    = 'pass'; $CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_'; $CFG->dboptions = array (   'dbpersist' => 0,   'dbport' => '',   'dbsocket' => '',   'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci', );

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/moodle'; $CFG->dataroot  = 'L:\\xampp\\moodledata'; $CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');
```

I have connected to AWS using Putty from windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cat` and heredoc:

```
cat > config.php <<'EOF'
your content
goes here
EOF
```

And you can skip `touch` this way.